# Docker unantended installation of imagemagick

Tags: docker

Hello i am pretty new to docker and try to create an .dockerfile where python and imagemagick works together with fastapi. Almost al the steps are going fine except the

> RUN sudo apt-get install libmagickwand-dev --no-install-recommends -y

This returns the following result:

```
 => [29/30] RUN sudo apt-get install libmagickwand-dev --no-install-recommends -y                                                                                                                                                    2371.7s 
 => => # questions will narrow this down by presenting a list of cities, representing
 => => # the time zones in which they are located.
 => => #   1. Africa      4. Australia  7. Atlantic  10. Pacific  13. Etc
 => => #   2. America     5. Arctic     8. Europe    11. SystemV
 => => #   3. Antarctica  6. Asia       9. Indian    12. US
 => => # Geographic area:
```

is it posible to give some parameters to the install **libmagickwand-dev** automatic on the image?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `noninteractive` mode like that:

```
RUN DEBIAN_FRONTEND="noninteractive" apt-get install libmagickwand-dev --no-install-recommends -y
```

Comment: Which option does it select ?

Comment: It sets `DEBIAN_FRONTEND` environment variable.