# Install ImageMagick to docker

Tags: docker, dockerfile, imagemagick

I'm running a python script to manipulate pictures. I was using an ImageMagick binding for python called wand.
Here is the Dockerfile.

```
FROM ubuntu:latest

RUN apt update
RUN apt install python3 -y
RUN apt-get -y install python3-pip
RUN pip install pillow
RUN pip install wand


WORKDIR /usr/app/src
COPY image_converter.py ./
COPY test_image_converter.py ./

RUN python3 -m unittest test_image_converter.py
```

And this is the error message

```
ImportError: MagickWand shared library not found.
You probably had not installed ImageMagick library.
Try to install:
  https://docs.wand-py.org/en/latest/guide/install.html
```

Answer (score 0):

Alright I got it thanks to this one [Docker unantended installation of imagemagick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65551091/docker-unantended-installation-of-imagemagick)

```
RUN DEBIAN_FRONTEND="noninteractive" apt-get install libmagickwand-dev --no-install-recommends -y
```